# Same process running for multiple tests in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a set of test that I would like to run in `pytest` which all depend on a third party executable to run. This executable generates output files and figures that I would like to test against some pre-made reference files and figures.

Currently, I am doing something like this:

```
import pytest

def test_1:
    os.system('executable')
    # compare data

def test_2:
    os.system('executable')
    # compare data

def test_n:
    os.system('executable')
    # compare data
```

However this is significantly slower than it needs to be, as I am running the same process multiple times.

What is a cleaner and more efficient way to do this via `pytest`?

Comment: Do you want each test to be run individually or all at once? If you're not modifying the output, you could reuse it.

Comment: I want to be able to do both. The output (i.e the group of output files)  would not change for each test, but each tests will do comparisons for a different subset of the output... if that makes any sense...

Comment: Then you could check for the files and, if needed, run the process. Else, just do the test without running the command again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fixture with `scope="module"` to easily achieve this (will run only once per module). If your tests are going to be in more than one module, use scope `session` (will run only once) and put it in conftest.py.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def create_files():
    os.system('executable')

def test_1():
    # work with the files
    pass

def test_2():
    # work with the files
    pass

def test_n():
    # work with the files
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks... I had figured this out in the meantime. It's also nice that fixtures at a module scope will run for individual tests as well..